# Копирование папок с файлами при обработке

Tags: delphi

Код обрабатывает файлы и копирует их с папок в ***\Моя_папка***. Как исправить код что бы с файлами копировались и папки в которых они были расположены?

То есть сейчас у меня есть папка: **Test** и в ней папки **Test1 + Test2 + Test3** - Код обрабатывает все файлы (что в папках **Test1 + Test2 + Test3**) и копирует их в указанную папку - ***\Моя_папка***.

**А нужно что бы и с файлами копировались и папки в которых они расположены.**

```
Var
f1, f2: File;
OldName, path, format, S: string;
file_list: TStringList;
flname1, flname2: string;

begin
file_list := TStringList.Create;

..............

  // Тут идет цикл
  for v := 0 to file_list.Count - 1 do
  begin
    flname1 := file_list.Strings[v];

    // Формируем новое имя в файле
    OldName := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + '\Моя_папка'; // Куда копировать
    path := ExtractFilePath(OldName); // извлекаем путь до файла
    format := extractfilename(flname1); // извлечь формат файла с цикла

// Вот тут и загвоздка !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    flname2 := path + 'NEW' + format; // Чтобы при формировании новых файлов с ними создавалась их папка

    assignfile(f1, flname1); // От куда копировать
    assignfile(f2, flname2); // Куда копировать

    reset(f1, 1);
    rewrite(f2, 1);

   // обработка файлов
    while not eof(f1) do
    begin
      .. .. .. и далее обработка файла 

     // Закрытие файлов
      closefile(f1);
      closefile(f2);
    end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для получения имени папки нам потребуется функция `ExtractFileName`. Она на самом деле возвращает строку, идущую после последнего разделителя, а это может быть как и имя файла, так и имя папки. Функция `ExtractFilePath` возвращает структуру папок с разделителем в конце, осталось только этот разделитель удалить в результате этой функции удалить.

```
function ExtractLastFolder(AFilename: string): string;
begin
  Result := ExtractFilePath(AFilename);

  Delete(Result, Length(Result), 1);

  Result := ExtractFileName(Result);
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

может тебе поможет вот этот ответ
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29183270/copy-everything-from-a-source-directory-to-a-new-directory-delphi-ex7  (через TDirectory.GetFiles и TPath.Combine, TFile.Copy)

Так же нашел функцию SHFileOperation (поcмотри там http://www.delphigroups.info/2/ac/412333.html)